# BroadcastReceiver not called after close my application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am trying to show a notification to user at fixed time. I am using `BroadcastReceiver` to show notification. Problem is that, `BroadcastReceiver` only called when application is running in foreground or background. But `BroadcastReceiver` not called after when I close application (means kill application). I am using `AlarmManager` to call `BroadcastReceiver`.

I read somewhere on stackoverflow that we don't to make service specifically to call `BroadcastReceiver`. We just need to register it in `AndroidManifest`.

I am using Xiomi Redmi 3s prime device and android version is 6.0.1.

So what I am missing? Why `BroadcastReceiver` not called?

This is my class from where I am triggering `AlarmManager`

```
public class Settings extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings,container,false);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BroadcastReciever.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class BroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Intent nofificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        nofificationIntent.putExtra("notify_key","notify_value");

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,1,
                        nofificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.donate)
                        .setSound(alarmSound)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setContentTitle("Whats up")
                        .setContentText("Hello world");

        int mNotificationId = 001;

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.nf">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Home"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".AndroidDatabaseManager"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <receiver android:name="broadcast.BroadcastReciever"
            android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tested my app on other mobiles phones and code working fine on other phones. Possibly there is some internal customization in mi devices miui os which is stopping broadcast to call.

Answer (score 2):

Use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead

Helper for the common pattern of implementing a `BroadcastReceiver` that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a `Service`, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition.

This class takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for you; you must request the `WAKE_LOCK` permission to use it.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) here

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

In Activity :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyFirstService.class));
}
```

In Service :-

public class MyFirstService extends Service 
{

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    Notification note = new Notification(0,null,System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(42, note);
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    stopForeground(true);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    return   START_STICKY;
}
```

}

In Broadcast :-

In broadcast write the code after create serivce .